# Переопределить метод класса Python

Tags: python, переопределение

В configparser есть класс `class RawConfigParser(MutableMapping):` с методом

```
def optionxform(self, optionstr):
       return optionstr.lower()
```

Который приводит к нижнему регистру. Мне нижний регистр наооборот не нужен. Как его переопределить? Спасибо

Comment: А в чём сложность? Наследуетесь от этого `RawConfigParser` и переопределяете.

Comment: Пока не умею, опишите по подробнее если не сложно, у меня что то не получается

Comment: Я его как бы переопредилил, Pycharm тоже не ругается, то все равно результат в нижнем регистре

Comment: а какой класс вы расширяете? расширяйте configparser и используйте свой класс вместо него

Answer (score 1):

Я все понял

```
import configparser

class MyConfigParser(configparser.ConfigParser):
    def optionxform(self, optionstr):
        return optionstr
```